# Hyperledger Fabric : How many peers are recommended for a channel?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, blockchain

I designed two organizations, each of whom has 1 channel.

To be safe from malicious peers, each channel has to contain as many peers as even if any peer's ledger is tampered it's difficult to tamper all the others' ledgers.

However, many of hyperledger-fabric examples in docs, tutorials, or textbooks set up one or two peers for one channel.

How many peers(endorsing and committing peers) are recommended for a channel?

Answer (score 0):

for ideal production environment you have to provide each organization in your network with at least 2 peers one of them will acting as anchor-peer and the other one will be acting in other roles even for gossip chat between peers.